# How to explain the equation 'Altitude of a star at culmination = co-latitude + declination'?

Tags: observational-astronomy

***Altitude of a star at culmination = co-latitude + declination***.
I understand that the co-latitude is equal to the altitude of the celestial equator (since it is 90 degrees away from the NCP). I also understand that declination is the height of a star above the celestial equator.

But I am just unsure why you can directly link altitude and declination at the exact point of culmination?
And why is a star reaching its highest point as it crosses the meridian?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the observer is at a geographic pole, the celestial equator is not parallel to the horizon but crosses it at an angle equal to the observer's colatitude.
A star's path across the sky is parallel to the celestial equator, with maximum altitude midway between the eastern and western horizons, i.e. on the meridian.

[image: Horizon and celestial equator from 40N]

*Rendered by Stellarium*

Comment: ah, thank you. 

So you can say that the celestial equator is at its maximum altitude as it crosses the meridian, and this maximum altitude is equal to the co-latitude?

Comment: @Matthew That's right.